# Json_format.parse() function throws error 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 11: invalid start byte

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to perform OCR on PDF files using google cloud vision, to do some basic testing i am using the sample code provided in google documentation in the below link, but the line of code provided below is throwing unicode decode error given below, can anyone please help me fix this, i did an extensive search and tried different approaches but i am unable to fix it.

```
response = json_format.Parse(json_string, vision.types.AnnotateFileResponse())
```

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf

Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 11: invalid start byte

Comment: How do the contents of "json_string" look like before parsing it?

Comment: Same issue. Any luck?